# Is there any way to restrict a class to create only 2 objects

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I know about singleton object design pattern.
How to allow a class to create only 2 different objects, then it should throw a error.

Comment: Same as singleton, but store instances in separated variables or in array. Still I do not see any logical use case for that :)

Comment: You're looking at the [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) pattern. With this, a singleton becomes a special case of the multiton pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A code version of @Ashwini's answer:

```
<?php

class Limited {
    private static $amount = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
            self::$amount++;
            if(self::$amount > 2) {
                    throw new Exception('Limit reached');
            }

            echo 'I am number ' . self::$amount . "\n";
    }
}

$obj1 = new Limited();
$obj2 = new Limited();

try {
    $obj3 = new Limited();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $obj3 = null;
    unset($obj3);
}
```

You should wrap every new instance in a try-catch so you can delete the object if it fails.

Answer (score 2):

One can do the following:

1. create static variable for the class.
2. Initialize it to 0.
3. Inside the constructor check the value of the static variable. If it exceeds 2, throw an error. else continue.